# Copy method from another AppDomain's assembly and execute it from CurrentDomain

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

In the big picture I am trying to execute method from dll in the main domain but after that, unload that dll. So far I've created new `AppDomain` loaded the `Assembly`\dll there, with `MarshalByRefObject` I fetched the body and `MaxStackSize` of the method to the main domain, created `DynamicMethod` there, recreated the body inside it and invoked it.
But when I invoke it I get exception:
`System.BadImageFormatException: Signature is not IMAGE_CEE_CS_CALLCONV_LOCAL_SIG`.

The code that fetches and invokes it:

```
DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod( "func", typeof( void ), new Type[ 0 ] );
var info = method.GetDynamicILInfo( );
info.SetCode( marshal.GetILCode( ), marshal.GetMaxStackSize());
info.SetLocalSignature(
    SignatureHelper.GetMethodSigHelper( CallingConventions.Standard, typeof( void ) ).GetSignature( ) );
method.Invoke( null, new object[ 0 ] ); //<-- exception here
```

`marshal` is an object of type [Proxy](http://pastebin.com/3yhPPcqN).
Some notes that might be necessary:

1. The method that I am fetching\invoking is `public static void Run();`.
2. The `AppDomain` that trying to invoke the method and the `AppDomain` that loads the dll\assembly have the same references.

**Edit**

I fixed the signature with changing the first byte to `0x07` from the `GetSignature` method.
But there's new problem `System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.`

Comment: Any reason you can't invoke the method in the other appdomain? You can't just rip out some piece of code. Who knows what it depends on? It certainly depends on the exact token values in its containing assembly's meta-data tables.

Comment: @usr I need it because the code may create new objects that I need to keep them after I unload the `AppDomain`. It doesn't depends on any of the things inside that dll. Just on the references. The code I tried to recreate is: `Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);`

Comment: It is complaining about your use of GetMethodSigHelper().  CallingConvention.Standard is only valid for unmanaged code with the __stdcall convention.  Not sure what the right flavor ought to look like, I'd certainly try DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate() first.

Comment: @HansPassant http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.callingconventions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx `Specifies the default calling convention as determined by the common language runtime. Use this calling convention for static methods.`, but I'll try.

Comment: @HansPassant Same exception.

Comment: True.  I was looking at the wrong overload, the one that takes CallingConvention without an "s".  I'm sure you need to post [an sscce](http://sscce.org/) to get help.

Comment: @HansPassant I knew it, I 'compressed' my question as I can. Actually I fixed the signature thing but there's another thing that popped up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation has a big fault, the byte array from [MethodBase.GetMethodBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) *is not portable*.

A method invocation using [OpCodes.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call.aspx) or [OpCodes.Callvirt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt.aspx) results in several bytes, one indicating the type of call (call/callvirt) followed by four bytes that represents a metadata token. This token can, in this case, be parsed as an Int32 and resolved to a MethodBase using [Module.ResolveMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k16h33dz.aspx).

Note that these metadata tokens are generated at compile time; they may differ between compilations. (While it's an implementation detail of the compiler, I believe they are just auto-incremented numbers based on the order of the methods seen during compilation.)

This means that the actual bytes you're trying to use contains metadata tokens that are invalid in your dynamic module. They may point to an existing method with a different signature than you're expecting, or may not be present at all in your module.

You would need to parse your il-code and emit everything again, thus generating new and valid metadata tokens.